# Почему cookie сохраняются только на текущей странице?

Tags: jquery, cookie, javascript, wordpress

Есть скрипт, который при клике на ссылку записывает куки и выводит текущий регион пользователя:

```
var cook = new $.cookie(); // создаем объект для работы с куками

   $("#rega a").click(function () {  
        cook.text = $(this).attr('title');
        cook.set({ expires: 300}); 
    });
                 cook.get(); // получаем куки
                 if((typeof(cook.text) != 'undefined' )) {
                     $("#city").html(cook.text);            
                 } 
                 if((cook.text == "undefined")) {
                     $("#city").html("Минск");      
                 }
```

Получается так, что, допустим, я на главной странице кликнул на Минск, то Минск будет только на главной, а если на другой странице ([mysite.com/another-page)](http://mysite.com/another-page)) кликнуть на другой регион, то только на этой другой странице будет выводится выбранный регион. Как сделать, чтобы выбранный кук на любой странице был на всех страницах, а не в отдельности? Надеюсь, понятно объяснил)

Comment: Идентичная проблема. Весь день убил пока не допёр что они сохраняются для отдельно взятой страницы, и ещё пол вечера ломаю голову как сделать их общими для всего домена.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте добавить путь:

```
// ...
cook.set({ expires: 300, path: '/'});
// ...
```

**path: '/'** - действительны для всего сайта

Comment: Добавлял, проблема осталась к сожалению и не знаю почему...Вот здесь столкнулись с той же проблемой: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326620/jquery-cookie-path

Кстати, хром вообще не принимает и не отображает куки, проблема оказалась в том что сайт на локалхосте, может быть опера не может правильно обработать path: '/' ?